# Swift query from Firebase not correctly awaited

Tags: swift, firebase, future, combine

I am trying to query documents from Firebase, but I am unable to to correctly await the response of the function. I have tried with Future, but seemingly I cannot return promise from within the query body. Could you help me, how to correctly query and then subscribe to it with Swift (Combine) and Firebase?

I need to know the result of the query (error/empty/success), and if success, then use the value of the query. Is this possible?

The query:

```
func getProductByCode(code: String) -> Future<[Product], QueryError> {
        return Future { promise in
            self.db.collection("products")
            .whereField("code", isEqualTo: code)
            .getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error on loading products: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return promise(.failure(.error))
                }
                
                if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
                    if querySnapshot.isEmpty {
                        print("Empty products list")
                        return promise(.failure(.empty))
                    } else {
                        self.products = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                            try? document.data(as: Product.self)
                        }
                        print("List of products: \(self.products)")
                        return promise(.success(self.products))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

enum QueryError: Error {
        case empty
        case error
    }
```

The method call, with subscription:

```
productRepository.getProductByCode(code: qrText)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(.error):
                print("ERROR on retrieving products")
            case .failure(.empty):
                print("EMPTY products")
            default:
                print("ALRIGHT")
            }
        }, receiveValue: { value in
            print("Returned value: \(value)")
            // Here I should get the result of the query and then use it.
        })

//After the method call I would like to use the result value.
//But I cannot correctly await it.
//It would be called before the async function returns the value.
```

I am open to any kind of change, I have tried Future, because it can return promises and we can subscribe to it. If there is a better solution to this kind of situation, please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly. The crux of the issue is the asynchronous nature of the network request.

```
productRepository.getProductByCode(code: qrText)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(.error):
                print("ERROR on retrieving products")
            case .failure(.empty):
                print("EMPTY products")
            default:
                print("ALRIGHT")
            }
        }, receiveValue: { value in
            print("Returned value: \(value)")
            // Here I should get the result of the query and then use it.
        })

// You want to use the value here? For example:
self.label.text = value
```

Can you use a function instead to accomplish what you'd like to use the value for, or put your code that uses the value within the `receiveValue` block? For example:

```
productRepository.getProductByCode(code: qrText)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
            switch completion {
            case .failure(.error):
                print("ERROR on retrieving products")
            case .failure(.empty):
                print("EMPTY products")
            default:
                print("ALRIGHT")
            }
        }, receiveValue: { value in
            print("Returned value: \(value)")
            updateLabel(value: value) // <- Function won't be called until this block fires and we have the `value`
        })

func updateLabel(value: String) {
    self.label.text = value
}
```